# Please suggest free Flowchart control for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html, charts

I need to build a flowchart control for ASP.NET with HTML/jQuery/Silverlight/SVG. The user need to design the flowchart in the web page and need to save it.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

It's a general SVG library rather than specifically flow charts, but it does look like it can do what you want -- see the links to the demos on the main page; one of them is a simple flow-chart, complete with draggable components.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes i'm trying http://www.jointjs.com/ ,that also implemented with raphaeljs .Thanks for ur suggestion.