# ASP.NET Visual diagram\ flowchart control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jsplumb, microsoft-glee

I am looking for a diagram\ graph\ flowchart user control for web application preferably ASP.NET.

My wish would be to pass a Graph object that contains a collection of nodes and edges and the capabilities that i would look for are:

1. Add a new node.
2. Connect two nodes together with an edge.
3. Delete nodes and edges
4. Automatic layout algorithm to minimize crossing of layers and edges

I found parts of the solution that will help me to create such a component such as:

1. JSPlumb or Raphael to draw the graph on the clients.
2. GLEE\ MSAGL to automatically order the graph in visual terms.

All of these will allow me to construct a component but i was wondering if anyone have already seen something that is web based and could do the task?
hopefully its open source :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [Dracula Graph Library](http://www.graphdracula.net/)? It looks like it would handle part 4 very well. You would only have to wire up some edit controls for the user.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4657455/168097) SO question apart from Raphael there is [jointjs.com](http://jointjs.com) worth checking out

Comment: True but this gets you really close to what you need. #4 is something I suspect you will find in the not free/open source libraries. @Mortalus if you think my answer is not helpful I will delete it.

Comment: Thanks it is not an answer but you are introducing another drawing options .. so I won't mind keeping it here but I caanot award the bounty as it is not an answer to the question ...

Comment: To be honest I was trying to help that's why I offered to delete this answer if it wasn't of help.